# Redirect to section on page(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 pages on one of it I have sections

Here is page with sections

```
    <section id="about" class="container content-section ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">VRed Ukraine</h2>
            <p style="text-align:center;">
            </p><p style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                <b>
                    VreD – сокращение от virtual reality education. Мы организовали первые курсы по обучению созданию виртуальной реальности. Рынок Украины, как и мировой в ближайшие 2 года будет быстрыми шагами двигаться в сторону VR. На данный момент на 2 разработчика приходится 3 заказчика. Это потому, что разработчик виртуальной реальности непростой боец. Его знания должны включать в себя:
                </b>
            </p>
            <div>
                <ul style="margin-top:50px;font-size:20px;">
                    <li>Умение создавать и работать с 3D моделями.</li>
                    <li style="margin-top:10px;">Умение правильно сканировать и обрабатывать объекты. </li>
                    <li style="margin-top:10px;">Умение работать со светом.</li>
                    <li style="margin-top:10px;">Умение работать с фото / видео 360.</li>
                    <li style="margin-top:10px;">Умение писать код и знать хотя бы один из популярных движков: Unity 3D / Unreal engine 4.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Каждые 2 месяца мы проводим открытые конференции. Если вам интересно попасть на них или получать полезную информацию о VR - оставьте свою почту.</p>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <button class="bolshe-button" style="margin-top:45px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Оставить почту</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></section>

<!-- Download Section -->


<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="container content-section text-center">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="text-align:center;">
            <h2>Контакты</h2>
            <p style="margin-top:20px;">+38(050)800-00-99</p>
            <p style="margin-top:20px;">+38(093)764-90-42</p>
            <p style="margin-top:20px;">
                <a href="mailto:info@vred.com.ua">info@vred.com.ua</a>
            </p>
            <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Vred-239810069850829/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> <span class="network-name">Facebook</span></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

On this page I scroll between pages via id's:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
            <li class="hidden">
                <a href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="padding-top:10px;font-size:20px;" class="">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">О нас</a>
            </li>

            <li style="padding-top:10px;font-size:20px;" class="active">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Контакты</a>
```

I need to make redirect from another page to contact section

Now I make redirect it like this:

```
   <li style="padding-top:10px;font-size:20px;" class="active">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Контакты</a>
                </li>
```

It opens page, but not goes to section, how I can make it goes to section?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")#about">Контакты</a>
```

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: it don't works :(

Comment: works for me with a div element. Instead of using <section> (if you just want to create a sub-part and you're not doing anything specific with <section> just use a div